# Как скрыть элементы у родителей с jquery?

Tags: jquery

не пойму как скрыть "del" только у тех элементов у которых есть дочерние
https://jsfiddle.net/KLON/2z7xpqrt/10/

чтобы выдить del только у:

```
 категория 1.1.1
 категория 1.2.1
 категория 2.1.1
 категория 2.2.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать псевдоклассы:

```
$("ul > li").find(":last").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: а last что конкретно мы ищем?

Comment: последний дочерний элемент в ваших вложенных списках. Попробуйте на вашем jsfiddle.